# js API data detect and giving colour

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to achieve in with javascript  a mechanism that can detect and colour different value's
(positive = green, negative = red). The data is from an API (https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/)

The problem that i have right now:
The colour of the data doesnt change.

problem:https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhob4.jpg

Javascript:

```
$.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/", function(data, status) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    if (data[i].id == "ethereum") {
$("#percent_change_1h").html(data[i].percent_change_1h + "%");  
      $("#percent_change_24h").html(data[i].percent_change_24h + "%");  
      $("#percent_change_7d").html(data[i].percent_change_7d + "%"); 
       {
        if ((data[i].percent_change_7d) < 0) {
            $('.percent_change').addClass("negative");
        } else if ((data[i].percent_change_7d) > 0) {
            $('.percent_change').addClass("positive");
        }
    };
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<table class="percent_change">
    <tr>
        <td>1hr </td>
        <td>24hr</td>
        <td>7days</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="percent_change_1h"></td>
        <td id="percent_change_24h"></td>
        <td id="percent_change_7d"></td>
    </tr>
```

CSS:

```
.positive { 
    color:green;
}

.negative { 
    color:red;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's `data`?. Further, we're not capable to help you with that shared code.  Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Every column must be negative when its value is negative?

Comment: "This isnt working" is very ambiguous. How is it not working?

Comment: Please provide sample data. Then it will be easy to answer

Comment: @Ele Thank you for your comment if rewrote my question.

Comment: @spyshiv I added an example

Comment: @dan08 I Rewrote my question

Comment: and? any changes?

Comment: Do you understand that you are getting 100 "records", and it's the last record that determines the values and color in your "output"? and, the value of  `available_supply` in that data is *always positive* - makes sense, you can't have a negative amount of supply

Comment: Do you want the entire table with color red when `(data[i].available_supply) < 0` is true?

Comment: @JaromandaX Wow very stupid mistake instead of "available_supply" I need to put in "percent_change_7d". Now the text doesnt have a colour.

Comment: @Ele I prefer only the number data

Comment: @hypern00b Why are you ignoring my answer entirely?

Comment: @ChrisG I upvoted your answert was helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra open curly-brace:

```
{
^   if ((data[i].percent_change_7d) < 0) {
```

To apply the style, use this:

```
if ((data[i].percent_change_7d) < 0) {
    $('#percent_change_7d').addClass("negative");
} else if ((data[i].percent_change_7d) > 0) {
    $('#percent_change_7d').addClass("positive");
}
```

```js
$.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/", function(data, status) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    if (data[i].id == "ethereum") {
      $("#percent_change_1h").html(data[i].percent_change_1h + "%");
      $("#percent_change_24h").html(data[i].percent_change_24h + "%");
      $("#percent_change_7d").html(data[i].percent_change_7d + "%");
      
      if ((data[i].percent_change_7d) < 0) {
        $('#percent_change_7d').addClass("negative");
      } else if ((data[i].percent_change_7d) > 0) {
        $('#percent_change_7d').addClass("positive");
      }
    };
  }
});
```

```css
.positive {
  color: green;
}

.negative {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="percent_change">
  <tr>
    <td>1hr </td>
    <td>24hr</td>
    <td>7days</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="percent_change_1h"></td>
    <td id="percent_change_24h"></td>
    <td id="percent_change_7d"></td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should take care of it:

```js
function show(eth) {
  $("#eth td").each(function(i, el) {
    let num = eth[this.id];
    if (num < 0) $(this).addClass("negative");
    if (num > 0) $(this).addClass("positive");
    $(this).html(num + "%");
  });
}

$.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/", function(data, status) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    if (data[i].id == "ethereum") show(data[i]);
  }
});
```

```css
.positive {
  color: green;
}

.negative {
  color: red;
}

td {
  padding: 0.2em
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="percent_change">
  <tr>
    <td>1hr </td>
    <td>24hr</td>
    <td>7days</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="eth">
    <td id="percent_change_1h"></td>
    <td id="percent_change_24h"></td>
    <td id="percent_change_7d"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```